# Zend Framework: How can i change class name of a form?

Tags: zend-framework

The default class name of the zend framework is "zend_form" and the elements of that form is created with dl,dt,dd tags.

How can i change this format and the class name of that form?

And also how can i change the format from dl,dd,dd to

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML class attribute on the form or the actual PHP class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML rendered by the form is controlled via decorators. This is a good place to start learning about them - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.form.decorators.html

If you provide an example of the markup you'd like to generate, I can show you a decorator scheme that should work.

As for the class name, assuming you're talking about the HTML form element's `class` attribute, simply set it using the `Zend_Form::setAttrib()` method, eg

```
$form->setAttrib('class', 'my-css-class');
```

Comment: Thanks, i want in this format,  <table> <tr> <td>lable ...</td> <td>input textbox...</td><tr/> <tr>....</tr> <tr>....</tr> .

Comment: Table based decorator schemes are notoriously difficult but have been done before. Try Google-ing "zend form decorators table"